# OOjava BlueJ: foreach not applicable to expression type

Tags: java

I get this error with this code:

```
public class Cafévoetbalploeg
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private String naam;
private int stichtingsjaar;
private String plaats;
private int totaalDoelpunten;
private int aantalGewonnenWedstrijden;
private Wedstrijdlijst wedstrijdlijst;    

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Cafévoetbalploeg
 */
public Cafévoetbalploeg() {
    stichtingsjaar = 0;

}    

/**
 *De naam van de ploeg
 *
 *@param ploegnaam geef de naam van de ploeg in
 */
public void naam(String ploegnaam) {
    naam = ploegnaam;        
}

/**
 *Het stichtingsjaar
 *
 *@param jaar geef het stichtingsjaar in
 */
public void stichtingsjaar(int jaar) {
    stichtingsjaar = jaar;        
}
/**
 *De locatie waar de ploeg speelt
 *
 *@param geef de locatie in waar de ploeg speelt
 */
public void plaats(String locatie) {
    plaats = locatie;
}

public int getAantalGewonnenWedstrijden (int jaar) {
    for (Wedstrijd w: wedstrijdlijst) 
    {
        if(wedstrijd.getJaar() == jaar) {
            w = wedstrijd;
        }              
    }       
}    

/**
 * Geef de naam van de ploeg
 * 
 * @return naam de naam van de ploeg
 */
public String naam() {
    return naam;
}
/**
 * Geef het stichtingsjaar van de voetbalploeg
 * 
 * @return stichtingsjaar het stichtingsjaar van de ploeg
 */
public int stichtingsjaar() {
    return stichtingsjaar;
}
/**
 * Geef de plaats waar de ploeg speelt
 * 
 * @return plaats de plaats van de ploeg
 * 
 */
public String plaats() {
    return plaats;
}
```

}

It got stuck here:

`for (Wedstrijd w: wedstrijdlijst)`

I am just a beginner in java so i don't know how to solve this error.

Why does this not work?

---

```
import java.util.*;
```

/**
 * Write a description of class Wedstrijdlijst here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

public class Wedstrijdlijst
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own

```
private ArrayList<Wedstrijd> wedstrijden;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Wedstrijdlijst
 */
public Wedstrijdlijst()
{
   wedstrijden = new ArrayList<Wedstrijd>();

}

public void nieuweWedstrijd(Wedstrijd wedstrijd) {

    wedstrijden.add(wedstrijd);


}
```

This is my class Wedstrijdlijst

Comment: Define "it got stuck". Do you get an error message? If so, which one?

Comment: The error i got is in the title!

Answer (score 3):

Because the Wedstrijdlijst class doesn't implement the [Iterable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? I made an arraylist in a class Wedstrijdlijst named wedstrijden

Comment: @Thomas, as I suspected. See my answer.

Comment: then you need to do for (Wedstrijd w : wedstrijdlijst.getWedstrijden()) to iterate on the java.util.List (which implements Iterable) inside the Wedstrijdlijst

Answer (score -1):

The [enhanced for loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) or the for-each loop is a new feature in Java5 to help iterate through Iterables (classes implementing the `Iterable` interface) and over arrays.

So you can have something like

```
List<String> names = ...
...
for(String name : names)
{
}
```

So, for your `for (Wedstrijd w: wedstrijdlijst)` to work, your `wedstrijdlijst` should implement `Iterable`.

BTW, What does the class `Wedstrijdlijst` contain? If it has a list of some sort inside (After you comment, looks like this is the case), like

```
class Wedstrijdlijst
{
   private List<Wedstrijd> list
   ...
   public getList()
   {
   }
   ...
```

then you will be able to loop through the list:

```
for (Wedstrijd w: wedstrijdlijst.getList())
```

Also, if this is your design, try revisiting it. You may not even a separate `Wedstrijdlijst` class. A `java.util.List` in the `Cafévoetbalploeg` class should be sufficient)

**Update:**

You dont need the `Wedstrijdlijst` class at all. In the `Cafévoetbalploeg`, remove `Wedstrijdlijst wedstrijdlijst` and add `ArrayList<Wedstrijd> wedstrijden`

Now you can loop over wedstrijden as you wanted.

Comment: import java.util.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class Wedstrijdlijst here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

public class Wedstrijdlijst
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
   
    private ArrayList<Wedstrijd> wedstrijden;
    
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Wedstrijdlijst
     */
    public Wedstrijdlijst()
    {
       wedstrijden = new ArrayList<Wedstrijd>();
        
    }
    
    public void nieuweWedstrijd(Wedstrijd wedstrijd) {
        
        wedstrijden.add(wedstrijd);
        

    }